# Angular shortcut working everywhere on the computer

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem.

I create some keyboard shortcuts on my app. But, I want this shortcuts working everywhere on the computer, even if my web app is open on my browser and I'm on an other application like league of legends etc..

If anyone can help me

Thanks

Comment: If the user clicks a ```<input type="text">```, then you can show the **angular-simple-keyboard**.

```npm i angular-simple-keyboard```

[angular-simple-keyboard demo](https://franciscohodge.com/projects/simple-keyboard/demo-showcase/)

Comment: So you want your app to handle keyboard events even when the app doesn't have focus?

Comment: Yes Kurt, this is what I want